# Qt6 C++ ownership of QObject when using QML_ELEMENT

Tags: qt, qml, ownership, qt6

I've started learning QML with Qt6 lately and am trying to apply "best practices" right from the start. When it comes to [integrating C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html) it seems that a family of macros (QML_ELEMENT and friends) is going to replace the old style *register functions. A [best practices talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mImptIBmWW0) on the Qt youtube channel calls this "declarative registration". I've tried that in a small example using CMake and it practically worked out of the box.

Now to my knowledge C++ classes exported and instantiated within a QML module have "QML engine" ownership. Lets suppose I'd rather have C++ take ownership of my class and QML merely use it, how would I inform the QML engine about my instance? Do I need to use [setContextProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) for that?

I've also wondered what benefits and drawbacks I'd get from letting either C++ or QML handle ownership? There seems to be hardly any information on those topics. I've even browsed a couple of Qt books and not a single one would elaborate on that...

Comment: You can explicitly call `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(myObject, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership)`, if you can get a pointer to your object. But it would be easier to use setContextProperty on an object already created in C++.

Comment: I probably should have watched the best practices talk a little longer. Somewhere around minute 8 they mention that there is a new alternative to [setContextProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) called [setInitialProperties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlapplicationengine.html#setInitialProperties).